# Disabled checkbox после совпадения значений

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть форма с двумя таблицами, в которых есть чекбоксы. Суть вопроса в следующем: как, если во второй таблице значение

```
value="1"
```

выбранного чекбокса, совпадает со значением

```
value="1"
```

чекбокса(не важно выбранного или нет) первой таблицы, запретить выбор чекбокса в первой таблице?

**UPD**

```html
    <form id="balance">
      <table class="table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>#</th>
      <th>XXX</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr th:each="en,iterStat : ${balances}" th:object="${en}">
            <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="1"></td>
         <td>YYY</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
      </table>

      <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>XXX</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr th:each="en,iterStat : ${balances}" th:object="${en}">
       <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="upBalances[]" value="1"></td>
       <td>YYY</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
    <div align="right">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" form="balance" value="Processing">
    </div>
```

Comment: Лучше приведите в вопросе уже отрендеренный html + ваши потуги на js. Приведенная вами верстка должна быть сперва обработана шаблонизатором (Thymeleaf, я так понимаю?)

Comment: @Darth, по моему шаблонизаторы тут не причем. Считайте что его нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В лоб

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#table2 input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
  var t2_cb_val = this.value;
  var checked_is_true = false;
  
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    checked_is_true = true;
  } else {
    checked_is_true = false;
  }
  
  $("#table1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
    var t1_cb_val = this.value;
      if (t2_cb_val == t1_cb_val) {
        if (checked_is_true) {
          $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
          $(this).prop('disabled',false);
        }
      }
  });
  

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="balance">
      <table id="table1">
     <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>#</th>
      <th>X</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr th:each="en,iterStat : ${balances}" th:object="${en}">
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="1"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="2"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="3"></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="4"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="5"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="7"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="8"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="9"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
      </table>

      <table id="table2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Y</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr th:each="en,iterStat : ${balances}" th:object="${en}">
            <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="3"></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="4"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="5"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="7"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="8"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"  class="i-checks" name="balances[]" value="9"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
    <div align="right">
       <!--<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" form="balance" value="Processing">-->
    </div>
```

Comment: после `disabled` когда я снимаю птичку обратно то `disabled` не удаляется с других чекбоксов.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan забыл, переделал

Comment: @programmer403,  как быть если значение value передается на сервер а значение с которым должен работать ваш код выше это совсем другое свойство..поясню в первой таблице value=balance.id, во второй таблице value=voucher.id,  а дизэйбл должен происходить если значения balance.provider.id первой таблицы и voucher.provider.id второй таблицы равны

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо большое за помощь!